# EditView only displays the last line of the text file

Tags: java, android

my App saves the text of a multi-line `EditView` to a text file, but the problem is that if I restart my app, only the last line gets restored. (Perhaps it's also possible that the `FileOutputStream` only saves the last line, I am not sure ¯_(ツ)_/¯)

Here is my code:

```
private static final String TAG = "EditDataActivity";
public static String Textfile = "test.txt";
private Button btnSave,btnDelete;
private EditText editable_item;
EditText Zutaten, Zubereitung;


DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private String selectedName;
private int selectedID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    editable_item = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Zutaten = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Zubereitung = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Zutaten.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            try{
                EditText test = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
                String testText = test.getText().toString();
                String Textfile2 = testText + ".txt";
                EditText field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                String text = field.getText().toString();
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Textfile2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        }
    });
    Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();


    selectedID = receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1); //NOTE: -1 is just the default value


    selectedName = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");


    editable_item.setText(selectedName);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                EditText test = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
                String testText = test.getText().toString();
                String Textfile2 = testText + ".txt";

                EditText field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                String text = field.getText().toString();
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Textfile2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(text.getBytes());
                fos.close();

            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rezept erfolgreich gespeichert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent back = new Intent(EditDataActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
            String item = editable_item.getText().toString();
            if (!item.equals("")) {
                mDatabaseHelper.updateName(item, selectedID, selectedName);
            } else {
                toastMessage("Du musst das Rezept benennen!");

            }


        }

    });



    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try{
                EditText test = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
                String testText = test.getText().toString();
                String Textfile2 = testText + ".txt";

                EditText field = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
                String text = field.getText().toString();
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(Textfile2, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                fos.write("".getBytes());
                fos.close();
                System.out.println("did it");

            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

            Intent back = new Intent(EditDataActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(back);
            mDatabaseHelper.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            editable_item.setText("");
            toastMessage("Rezept erfolgreich gelöscht!");



        }


    });

}

private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void loadsavedfile(){

    try {

        EditText test1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editable_item);
        String test1Text = test1.getText().toString();

        String Textfile2 = test1Text + ".txt";
        if (!Textfile2.isEmpty()) {


            FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(Textfile2);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new DataInputStream(fis)));
            String test;


            EditText Test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);

            while ((test = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Test.setText(test);
            }
        }else{

        }
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
```

Hope fully you can help me :)
Thanks!

Comment: It's your read loop. You are repeatedly setting the text to the last line read, and not accumulating it.

Comment: I changed it from `while ((test = reader.readLine()) != null) {` to ` test = reader.readLine();` but now it only restores the first Line. (As you might can tell, I am beginner)

Comment: You are Setting The String 'test' with Reader.readline() and assign this string with setText to 'Edittext Test' but you override the Set Text  with each newly read line from the file and you will just see the last line from the file at the end, because you've overwritten all lines before.

Comment: I figured that out already (but thanks anyway), I use `append` now but unfortunately it's storing everything in the same line

Comment: So add a newline to each line. `readLine()` removes them. Nobody told you to remove the loop.

Comment: NB When you catch an exception, print the exception, not just "Error!". It makes debugging impossible, and also problem reporting by the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
while ((test = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Test.setText(Test.getText()+"\n" + test);
            }
```

When you had setText(test) only it was replacing the text from the edit text every time the loop ran but you have to append the new text to the last line. A better way to do this would be to create the String first and then set it to EditText as it is better for performance.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
while((test = reader.readLine()) != null)
    str.append('\n' + test);
Test.setText(str.toString());
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, this solved my problem
Really appreciate your help, thanks :)

Comment: Good to know it helped.